# Why this set is not convex?

Tags: complex-numbers, convex-analysis

Let
 $$M=\{(|x_1|^2,x_1\overline{x_2})\;\;\hbox{such that}\;x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2\;\hbox{and}\;|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2=1\},$$
Why this set is not convex? And thank you

Comment: Where did you get the question from?

Comment: For starters, do you have a good picture of the "domain" $\{(z_{1}, z_{2}) : |z_{1}|^{2} + |z_{2}|^{2} = 1\}$ and its "slices" $z_{1} = \text{constant}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take $(x_1,x_2)=(1,0)$, then you get that $(1,0)\in M$ and if you take $(x_1,x_2)=(0,1)$, then you get that $(0,0)\in M$. Is it true that $\left(\frac12,0\right)\in M$? No, because if $\left(\frac12,0\right)=\bigl(|x_1|^2,x_1\overline{x_2}\bigr)$ then $|x_1|^2=\frac12$ and therefore $|x_2|^2=\frac12$. But then $\bigl|x_1\overline{x_2}\bigr|=\frac12$, whereas $\left|0\right|=0$. Therefore, $M$ is not convex.

Comment: The  answer is not clear for me. Is the point $\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$ belongs to the  segment joining two points $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$?

Comment: I think we work with $\left(\frac12,  0\right)$ we get the result

Comment: @Student No. My mistake. Please take a look at the edited version and tell me what you think of it.

Comment: I wonder how is it possible that *three* persons upvoted my original answer...

Comment: Now the answer is very clear..Thank you.